# How can I correctly reference the original file and data from a source sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file "Dashboard" that has a preset set of analysis tables. I am trying to write this code so that it will run from the dashboard file (dim wbdashboard) and refer to a user designated source file (dim sourcesheet). The code will then copy the raw data over to the dashboard file so that the analysis can be updated.

If I run the code from the dashboard file I am getting an Runtime Error 9 - Subscript out of range. If I run the code manually from the editor with the source file active, I don't get an error.

```
Sub Dashboard_Analysis()

Dim wbDashboard As Workbook
Dim myNamedRange As Range, Rng As Range, c As Range, destrange As Range
Dim myRangeName As String
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim SourceSheetName As String
Dim SearchRow As Long, StartatRow As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim S As String
    
Set wbDashboard = ActiveWorkbook
    
Set SourceSheet = Application.InputBox("Select any cell inside the source sheet: ", _
"Prompt for selecting target sheet name", Type:=8).Worksheet
               
SourceSheetName = SourceSheet.Name

SearchRow = InputBox("Row # where Reference 'Dashboard' is entered.", "Row Input")
StartatRow = InputBox("Row # where Headers are located.", "Row Input")

Const RangeName As String = "Dashboard_Data_Raw"

lastRow = SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'loop cells in row to search...
For Each c In SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(SearchRow, 1), _
                       SourceSheet.Cells(SearchRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
    If LCase(c.Value) = "dashboard" Then 'want this column
        'add to range
        BuildRange myNamedRange, _
            SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(StartatRow, c.Column), SourceSheet.Cells(lastRow, c.Column))
       
    End If
Next c

'check if values are captures correctly
Debug.Print myNamedRange.Address 'correct range
Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name 'shows correct source file

'create named range (Dashboard_Data_Raw)

'---> this is where i am running into the error
Worksheets(SourceSheetName).Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=myNamedRange

Application.GoTo Reference:="Dashboard_Data_Raw"
Selection.Copy

'switching to dashboard file to continue with code

wbDashboard.Activate
Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Comment: `SourceSheet.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=myNamedRange`  You already have a reference to the sheet object: no need to go through the `Worksheets` collection.  FYI likely the error is because `Worksheets` (without any specified workbook qualifier) defaults to ActiveWorkbook, which is not necessarily where the sheet is located.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. For some reason it now gets hung up on the Application.GoTo code line. runtime error 1004 - Specified dimension not valid for... The activeworkbook is the same as the specified range.

Comment: `myNamedRange.Copy` would work unless you really need that `Goto`